# Getting data from xml and inserting into existing table using stored procedure and c#

Tags: c#, xml, stored-procedures, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

```
public int UpdatePlantContacts(int PlantID, List<string> PlantContacts)
{
    int i = 0;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("PlantAreaContact");
    dt.Columns.Add("PlantAreaID",System.Type.GetType("System.Int"));
    dt.Columns.Add("PlantAreaContact", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("IsAreaHead", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("AreaEmailID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("LoginPassword", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("SystemPermission", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows )
    {
        DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add("~/XmlData/PlantAreaContacts");
    }
    StringWriter XMLWriter = new StringWriter();
    dt.WriteXml(XMLWriter);
    System.Xml.Linq.XElement XMLUncertanity = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(XMLWriter.ToString());
    try
    {
        i = plcon.UpdatePlantContacts(PlantID, dt);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    if (i <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

This is my BAL code, I have xmldata in my vs2010 in my folder I want to insert the data in that and after that the xml data should insert using stored proc, below is my DAL

```
   public int UpdatePlantContacts(int PlantID, DataTable PlantContacts)
 {
    try
    {
        int result = -1;
            sqlcmd = fnProcedure("sp_UpdatePlantAreaContacts");
            SqlParameter par1 = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@PlantAreaID", SqlDbType.Int);
            par1.Value = PlantID;
            SqlParameter par2 = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int);
            par2.Value = 1015;
            //SqlParameter par3 = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            //par3.Value = "E:/QONE/P218/ENG/PlantAreaContactsXML.xml";
            SqlParameter par4 = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Return", SqlDbType.Int);
            par4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            try
            {
                fnOpen();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = Convert.ToInt32(sqlcmd.Parameters["@Return"].Value);
                fnClose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                fnClose();
                result = -1; ;
            }
            return result;
            //Conn.Close();
            //Conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            CreateErrorLog Err = new CreateErrorLog();
            Err.ErrorLog(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Logs/ErrorLog"), Ex.Message);
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        finally
        {
        }


}
```

And my stored proc is below
          ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PlantcontactUpdate]
          @PlantAreaID int,
          @Doc XML

```
      AS
     BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE ##temp

   select *
   into ##temp from  dbo.PlantAreaContact  where  PlantAreaID= @PlantAreaID
   begin try
   delete from dbo.PlantAreaContact where  PlantAreaID= @PlantAreaID

   DECLARE @idoc int 

   EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc
  -- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.
  insert into dbo.PlantAreaContact 
   SELECT   @PlantAreaID, *
    FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/DocumentElement/PlantAreaContacts',2)
        WITH (PlantAreaContact varchar(50),IsAreaHead int,AreaEmailID varchar(50),
        AreaMobileNumber varchar(25),LoginPassword varbinary(10),SystemPermission  varchar(25))

 end try   

  begin catch

delete from dbo.PlantAreaContact where  PlantAreaID= @PlantAreaID
insert into dbo.PlantAreaContact  select * from ##temp
drop table ##temp

RAISERROR ('Failed PlantAreaContact',16,1);
 end catch



END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to operate WriteXml for object dt (which is an empty object : `DataTable dt = new DataTable()`).

You need to write

```
PlantContacts.WriteXml("filepath");
```

Clarify if the requirement is different from my understanding